# IE 11 not rendering div on javascript properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using IE 11 , and it fails to render div dialog properly. All the dimensions viz. height, width, top, left give inappropriate results. The same is working fine for IE10.

The javascript code snippet is as follows:-

```
if (height > 0 && width > 0)
{
    myDialog.height = height;
    myDialog.width = width;
    myDialog.top = (parseInt(document.body.clientHeight) - height) / 3;
    myDialog.left = (parseInt(document.body.clientWidth) - width) / 2;
}
```

Here, myDialog is the div object I am talking about. why is this code snippet failing for IE11.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Depends on a lot of things you haven't posted, but the most important is, that `width` and `height` properties for `div` are obsoleted.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting properties on the `HTMLDivElement` instance. You may have more success setting them on its `style` property:

```
if (height > 0 && width > 0)
{
    myDialog.style.height = height + "px";
    myDialog.style.width = width + "px";
    myDialog.style.top = ((parseInt(document.body.clientHeight) - height) / 3)  + "px";
    myDialog.style.left = ((parseInt(document.body.clientWidth) - width) / 2)  + "px";
}
```

Note I've also added `px` to the end, since these are CSS-style measurements.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
if (height > 0 && width > 0)
```

{
    
myDialog.style.height = height;
    
myDialog.style.width = width;
    
myDialog.style.top = (parseInt(document.body.clientHeight) - height) / 3;
    
myDialog.style.left = (parseInt(document.body.clientWidth) - width) / 2;

}